# Backup app data from iOS8.3 to PC

Tags: backup, itunes, iphone, ios

I'm using Windows and always used the iFunBox-classic to be able to backup save games, but after the update to *iOS 8.3* trying to open the application by [iFunBox-classic](http://dl.i-funbox.com) display anything, it is a blank screen.

Backup other things is working. Updated iTunes to the latest version and (64bit), but the problem persists. I uninstalled it, rebooted, reinstalled iTunes and iFunBox, but the problem persists.

In [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com) (non-classic) show this message:

> App Sandbox access is restricted by Apple to ones with "iTunes File
>   Sharing" enabled since iOS 8.3. Jailbreak is required to open the
>   sandbox of this App.

I need to move *saves* (app data) from my old iPhone to the new iPhone. Is there any alternative to backup save from games without needing the jailbreak?

Comment: I think Apple effectively closed that door with 8.3. Jailbreak is likely your only option.

Comment: @Tetsujin Questions about jailbreak is offtopic? Like: *How to do jailbreak iOS8.3?* - Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Questions about Jailbreak are fine - I was just saying that may be your only option.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes I understand, just asked why you have more experience in the community and I do not know if jailbreak is seen as an "illegal" practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to jailbreak your phone as soon as you are able. The good news is that not only will you be free from the very limited App Store, but the process is entirely reversible! You can't void the warranty if they can't prove you ever did anything wrong, after all.

Comment: They could create a system to back up only the data, unfortunately it seems that they want to force us to go by evil way >:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have jailbreak on your device, you can use "Apps Manager" tweak (https://repo.xarold.com/pack/appdatamanager) to locally backup/restore data by app. It works fine even on iOS 10 and 11.